# point location convert between double and integer

Tags: c, geometry, data-conversion

I have a three-dimensional point set. Each point
holds its own coordinates (x,y,z) with double values. 
Now I want to convert all coordinates from the point set 
into integer values.

For example if my set consists of random points between the range 0.0 and
1.0. If I use `floor()` to convert into integers, I can't distinguish between
the results any more.

How do I convert them properly? Do I need some scaling?

Comment: try do use cast: int a = (int) 1.6d;

Comment: What do you expect to get? Of course if you truncate any number 0.xxxx you will get 0. You can prescale the numbers before, but the scale factor is depending on your accuracy requirement.

Comment: I agree with the `SCALE` and casting solution given by Wolf. But if you want to increase the accuracy of the result you have to add 0.5 before casting/rounding. `pi->x = (int)(SCALE * pd->x + 0.5);`. This because the cast will provide the lower integer. For example: (int)100.9 will give 100 not 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question about converting into `int` values suggests that you are going to display the points in a pixel display, here indeed scaling them first with a `double` then `floor` (or `ceil` or `round`) the values. Also a simple cast will do the conversion:

```
int pi.x = (int)pd.x;
```

Or, much simpler, the assignment itself.

```
int pi.x = pd.x;
```

The best solution would be to create a conversation function for the projection, thus you can decide later if there has to be done some more to get an image of the original points. Here is an example:

```
struct Point3Dd { double x, y, z; };
struct Point3Di { int x, y, z; };

double SCALE = 100.0;

void calc_projection(Point3Dd* pd, Point3Di* pi) {
    pi->x = SCALE * pd->x;
    pi->y = SCALE * pd->y;
    pi->z = SCALE * pd->z;
}
```